# WP7 emulator blank screen on startup

Tags: windows-phone-7.1.1

i created a basic phone project and started debugging, but the emulator shows only a blank screen.
the application is loading...i can see debug messages in visual studio output.

windows 7, visual studio 2010 and  SDK 7.1.1

graphics problems?